# Bluetooth scan with custom iac via DBus

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez

in my use case I have devices listening on a custom iac: e.g. 0x9e8b32 for security reasons.

I am able to find them via `hcitool scan --iac=0x9e8b32`.

But in my application I use the Bluez DBus API. 
So is there a way to set the IAC before setting the Adapter into Discovery mode?

```
$ bluetoothd --version
5.43
```

Comment: seems like there is a issue with bluez, but there is a work around (http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.bluez.kernel/52450)

Comment: I think my problem is different because `bluetoothctl` does't even find the device. The IAC in use is neither giac nor liac

Comment: IMO as of now adapter interface provides only filter using "DuplicateData, Transport, RSSI, UUIDs, Pathloss". So there isn't any direct control over iac.

Comment: Refer: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/src/adapter.c#n153

Comment: @WaeCo, looks like you completely didnt go through the thread, (https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg52229.html), so what you have to do is scan it via 'hcitool scan --iac=0x9e8b32'  once you have found your device open a separate window , now run hcitool cc with the dbus command to pair the device, (I have a C function here which calls the hcitool cc and the dbus command you just need to pass the device mac and controller mac http://prabhakarlad.blogspot.co.uk/2017/09/bluez5-pairing-devices-tricks.html)

Comment: @PrabhakarLad yes of cause I can just issue shell commands and parse the result, but having a library call would be much nicer.

Comment: @ParthibanN I guess then this is the answer, you know of any plans to support this?

Comment: @WaeCo I am not bluez developer. Please contact mailing list or IRC of bluez